# Flutter HMS Core Plugin Integration Error

Tags: flutter, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am using HMS Core plugin(Huawei Location Kit) in my application, everything works fine in **debug** mode, but when I switch it on release mode, it is throwing the following error even though I can  access to the Huawei Location Kit normally:

```
E/flutter (28815): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(-5, -5: Core error, null) E/flutter (28815): Warning: This VM has been configured to produce stack traces that violate the Dart standard.
```

I have no idea what might be causing the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if  you have added SHA in AppGallery Console correctly.

Please check if your json file is in correct place inside app folder.

And please exclude the HMS SDK from obfuscation.

Comment: obfuscation was causing the issue, now its working very well. Thanks